timed out while waiting for program to exit problem

My code prompts this when I checked 50.
Everything is going well in the code, just check 50 prompt. Just tell me what it shows in the picture.
import random
import sys

def main():
    level = get_level()
    generate_integr(level)


def get_level():

    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("level: "))

            if n == 1 or n == 2 or n == 3:
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return n


def generate_integr(level):

    operation = 10

    score = 0

    while operation != 0:
        if level == 1:
            x = random.randint(0, 9)
            y = random.randint(0, 9)
            response = int(input(f"{x}+{y}= "))

        elif level == 2:
            x = random.randint(10, 90)
            y = random.randint(10, 90)
            response = int(input(f"{x}+{y}= "))

        elif level == 3:
            x = random.randint(100, 900)
            y = random.randint(100, 900)
            response = int(input(f"{x}+{y}= "))

        if response == x + y:
            score = score + 1
            operation = operation - 1

        elif response != x + y:

            print("EEE")
            second_chance = int(input(f"{x}+{y}= "))

            if second_chance == x + y:
                score = score + 1
                operation = operation - 1

            elif second_chance != x + y:
                print("EEE")
                third_chance = int(input(f"{x}+{y}= "))

                if third_chance == x + y:
                    score = score + 1
                    operation = operation - 1

                elif third_chance != x + y:
                    print("EEE")
                    print(f"{x}+{y}=", x+y)
                    operation = operation - 1

        while operation == 0:
            break

    sys.exit(f"score:{score}")



main()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

The testing tool check50 imports your code professor.py and tries to test the single functions. But your file starts main() and this breaks the tests. You need a guard:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This allows to import and run single functions without running the whole program.
After I've fixed it, the test passes:
Results for cs50/problems/2022/python/professor generated by check50 v3.3.11
:) professor.py exists
:) Little Professor rejects level of 0
:) Little Professor rejects level of 4
:) Little Professor rejects level of "one"
:) Little Professor accepts valid level


The dangers of using an automated testing system without understanding what the tests do and why.
To my mind the guard is not mandatory (and is good practice which is applicable only when the module could be imported) - the fact that an automated tester flags this as a automatic failure (or fails when the guard is not present) raises my concerns.

@TonySuffolk66 IMO, the testing tool check50 is garbage (I've worked with it and have my reasons for this opinion). I'm only answering the question.

@jabbaa - it wasn't a comment against you - apologies for any misunderstanding.

@TonySuffolk66 No, you're totally right. It's not a good testing tool.
